# SHA1 MD5 Encoding doesn't return same hash

Tags: php, md5, sha1

we have existing user base on mysql with password encoded using md5 and sha1, with below logic -

```
// Password and salt generation
define('SALT_LENGTH', 9); // salt for password
function PwdHash($pwd, $salt = null)
{
    if ($salt === null) {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    } else {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    return $salt . sha1($pwd . $salt);
}
```

Now when we check the for a valid user this is what we perform -

```
// $pwd is password encoded and stored in db
// $pass is the password coming from UI

if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass, substr($pwd, 0, 9))) {
  // Perform something user is valid
}
```

Problem is the password coming from db doesn't match with the password coming from UI, however it works on server. Have tried multiple options without any success any pointer would really help.

Comment: Why are you designing your own password hash function instead of using the built-in `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`?

Comment: Like i said it is an existing application, and worked earlier by some other developer. We don't have much option to change the logic here.

Comment: Watch out for spaces around `$pass`, try `$pass = trim($pass);`

Comment: Sorry no difference even after trying `$pass = trim($pass);`

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Make sure you don't do any sanitization of the password before storing or checking it.